# Why actionLayout is not working in BottomNavigation?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a BottomNavigation in Android. I'm trying to put my own custom designs for each item within the BottomNavigation. For that, I have created a layout design of the item I want to show. I added that layout in the item with the help of menu xml using actionLayout. After all the code my layout is showing correctly within the menu xml but its not showing in the activity BottomNavigation. Here is my problem and code :

[Screenshot of main activity where the item design is not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vwbB.jpg)

[Screenshot of Menu XML where I'm seeing the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAKd4.jpg)

Here is my code -

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bott_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"/>
```

**navmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/item_home"/>
  

</menu>
```

**item_home.xml** (Item custom layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_full_rounded"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/itemTranBg"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_homeicon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="Home"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What makes you think a `BottomNavigationView` supports action layouts (it doesn't)?

Comment: What is another way to use my own custom item design for BottomNavigation? @ianhanniballake